# Getting the categoryId of a post in Graphql

Tags: wordpress, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, wp-graphql

This is my Graphql query for getting posts from headless wordpress:

```
export const GET_POSTS = gql`
 query GET_POSTS( $uri: String, $perPage: Int, $offset: Int, $categoryId: Int ) {
 
  posts: posts(where: { categoryId: $categoryId, offsetPagination: { size: $perPage, offset: $offset }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        excerpt
        slug
        featuredImage {
          node {
            ...ImageFragment
          }
        }
        categories {
          edges {
            node {
              categoryId
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      offsetPagination {
        total
      }
    }
  }
 }
 
 ${ImageFragment}
 
 `;
```

When i do this: `console.log("DATAAAA", data.posts.edges);`

i get:

```
    DATAAAA [
  {
    node: {
      id: 'cG9zdDo0MA==',
      title: 'postttt',
      excerpt: '<p>dlkfjdsflkdslkdjfkldsf</p>\n',
      slug: 'postttt',
      featuredImage: null,
      categories: [Object],
      __typename: 'Post'
    },
    __typename: 'RootQueryToPostConnectionEdge'
  },
  {
    node: {
      id: 'cG9zdDox',
      title: 'Hello world!',
      excerpt: '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n',
      slug: 'hello-world',
      featuredImage: null,
      categories: [Object],
      __typename: 'Post'
    },
    __typename: 'RootQueryToPostConnectionEdge'
  }
]
```

But when try to go further, inside `node`, like this: `console.log("DATAAAA", data.posts.edges.node);` in order to get the `categoryId` which is inside `categories: [Object]`, i get undefined.

How to get `categoryId` based on this query?

What i want to do is to get only the posts by a given category in `getStaticProps` like this, but i dont know how to get that `categoryId` dynamically. This is what my `getStaticProps` function looks like:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log("THE CONTEXT", context);
  const { data, errors } = await client.query({
    
    query: GET_POSTS,
    variables: {
      uri: context.params?.slug ?? "/",
      perPage: PER_PAGE_FIRST,
      offset: null,
      categoryId: <===== How to get this dynamically?
    },
  });

  const defaultProps = {
    props: {
      data: data || {},
    },
    
    revalidate: 1,
  };

  return handleRedirectsAndReturnData(defaultProps, data, errors, "posts");
}
```

This is my `getStaticPaths` function:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_CATEGORY_SLUGS_ID,
  });

  const pathsData = [];

  data?.categories?.edges.node &&
    data?.categories?.edges.node.map((category) => {
      if (!isEmpty(category?.slug)) {
        pathsData.push({ params: { slug: category?.slug } });
      }
    });

  return {
    paths: pathsData,
    fallback: FALLBACK,
  };
}
```

and this is what i get from context `console.log("THE CONTEXT", context);`:

```
THE CONTEXT {
  params: { slug: 'uncategorized' },
  locales: undefined,
  locale: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you try `console.log("DATAAAA", data.posts.edges[0].node);`?

Comment: edges appears to be an `array`.

Comment: i just edited my question to show what i get in that array. yes, its an array of posts. but i dont know how to tell nextjs to get only the posts which has that particular `categoryId`. look at the `getStaticProps` function. i need to get that `categoryId` and pass it to the Apollo client variables. When i hardcore the `categoryId` value in the `variables: {categoryId: 4}`, i get what i expect.

Comment: Do you have anything in `context.params` that can either provide you the `categoryId` or help you retrieve it from WordPress? Also, what does the path to that page look like?

Comment: @juliomalves i edited my question. I tried to find that in `context` but i only get the `slug` there. Wordpress doesn't pass the `categoryId` as params. Its in the query of the posts itself. Maybe i have to `.map` through the categories and pass it as props, but here my logic stops how to do it.